Runtime Error when setting view3d to Camera created in Script
I have found myself with a problem that I was hoping the community could help me with.
For context, the most basic version of the script I am working with is below and it produces the same RuntimeError:
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='VIEW', location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(1.36136, 2.85751e-07, 1.06814), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera()

The goal of this script is to simply create a scene camera and enter the view camera space in the the 3d viewport. However, when the script is executed, the camera is created but produces a RuntimeError::
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Tried to side step by using the following code with same result:
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='VIEW', location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(1.36136, 2.85751e-07, 1.06814), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera()

I can enter the view_camera mode manually once the camera is created with no issue but the script keeps erroring out. Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.
